# Inline rendering template override

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, rendering-template

Using SharePoint Designer, how can an inline rendering template be specified for a given SharePoint:FormField in a DataFormWebPart ?
For example, I want to arrange a multiple lookup field vertically, instead of the default horizontal layout.
I know I can do this with jQuery, but I'm looking for a pure HTML/markup solution.

I'm sure this is possible as I've done this before, but can't remember how (the blog I bookmarked with an example of what I'm trying to do is not available anymore).
I recall the solution involved copying the HTML markup of the given control from DefaultTemplate.ascx, modifying it according to the requirements and then copying it somehwere inside the `<SharePoint:FormField>`markup.
The solution could be fully performed in SharePoint Designer and did not involved any custom ascx control.

Thanks for your shedding some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, answering my own question.

It turns out that it's easy. The file `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\DefaultTemplates.ascx` contains all the predefined rendering templates for all the SharePoint form controls.

In order to override inline in SharePoint Designer (so, no deployment of features/controls is required) the rendering template of a control, copy all what is inside the `<Template></Template>` tag of the `<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>` and paste it in your custom form, inside the `<SharePoint:FormField>` whose template you want to override.

An example of overriding the default TextBox rendered for a field of type text:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" FieldName="MyField" Id="ff1{$Pos}" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@MyField')}">
    <Template>
      <asp:TextBox id="TextField" maxlength="255" runat="server"/>
     <!-- get rid of this annoying <br/>  tag -->
    </Template>
</SharePoint:FormField>
```

Now, your FormField will be rendered as TextBox, without the annoying `<br>` tag that is normally put after it.